# In String Slicing str [:3] , in case the string is less than length 3, will this slicing return or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

If I have a string of variable length and I want to return only first 3 characters of the string.

str[:3]

this works but I want to know if the string is of lesser length, suppose 2, "ab" or just "a", will this slicing work for that too?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! You know, you can always fire up a python command line and test it for yourself...

Comment: @ori6151 some of us are just Python theorists on here!

Comment: See the documentation and existing references for such trivial questions: “python slice string” or “python slice documentation” on google return relevant results. The following appears in the results - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Answer (score 1):

Python will return at most :n characters:
`'a'[:3]` will simply return `'a'`. `''[:3]` returns `''`.

Answer (score 1):

You could have tested for yourself in less time than it would have taken to open your browser.

But **yes**.